# A question was migrated, but I think it belongs in the original stack

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/what-are-free-rs-232-terminal-programs) was recently migrated from Electrical Engineering to Software Recommendations.  It is asking for a software interface to view the serial output of a microcontroller.

It is certainly asking for a software recommendation, but I think it's much more applicable to an EE Forum than a software forum.  The answers had more than 20 aggregate Upvotes in the EE Stack.  I would liken the question to "Should I use MPLAB X or MPLAB v8 for developing microcontroller code."  Definitely software related, but only for EE's :)

Am I incorrect?  Does it matter?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this got migrated because "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic" on EE. This is supposedly because those recommendations will quickly go out of date (which apparently doesn't apply to your question because every program that got mentioned is at least 10 years old). Also because this kind of question tends to invite discussion instead of having a single correct answer (which does apply to your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial reaction was to close it as off-topic  "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products [...]" (what @ThePhoton said).  Then I have remembered that a [stack for software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) was established recently, and I've migrate it over there.

We have closed a lot of software recommendation requests on EE.SE.

**Q:** What should one do, if one thinks that he has a software recommendation request, which should be addressed by EE.SE specifically?
**A:** Ask for recommendations in EE.SE **chat**.

Comment: Yup, I would vote to close that if it came back here.

Comment: Ha! In the face of 140k+ rep, I must accede! Thanks, guys, this a great community :)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to link @OlinLathrop 's account name...